# Why is my sample facebook xml rss feed generating errors after manual upload?

Tags: xml, facebook

I am trying to submit a sample product catalog feed to facebook before creating our full feed. I have tried building a sample feed in both rss and atom but always receive the error - "HTML format isn't supported." Seems I'm at an impass as one of our other devs said he thinks it looks fine. Here is a snippet of the feed with one product. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:g='http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'>
<title>Etrailer.com</title>
<link rel='self' href='http://www.etrailer.com'/>
<entry>
<g:id>SP01-120</g:id>
<g:title>1-1/2&quot; Square Trailer U-Bolts (Qty 2)  </g:title>
<g:description>Square Trailer U-Bolt Width: 1-1/2&quot; Diameter: 1/2&quot; Length: 5&quot; Threaded portion measures 2&quot; For 3,500-lb axles only Includes Lock Nuts 071090 Redline Square Trailer U-Bolts with Nuts and Washers</g:description>
<g:google_product_category>Vehicles &amp; Parts &gt; Vehicle Parts &amp; Accessories &gt; Motor Vehicle Parts &gt; Motor Vehicle Towing</g:google_product_category>
<g:product_type>Trailer Suspension &gt; U-Bolts &gt; U-Bolt &gt; For 1-1/2 Inch Square Axle &gt; 1/2 Inch Diameter &gt; 5 Inch Long</g:product_type>
<g:feature>U-Bolts U-Bolt</g:feature>
<g:link>http://www.etrailer.com/Trailer-Suspension/Redline/SP01-120.html</g:link>     
<g:image_link>http://www.etrailer.com/static/images/pics/S/P/SP01-120_3.jpg</g:image_link>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:price>12.99</g:price><g:brand>Redline</g:brand>
<g:gtin>640603169157</g:gtin>
<g:shipping>
<g:country>US</g:country>
<g:service>Ground</g:service>
<g:price>4.99 USD</g:price>
</g:shipping>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: If that is your actual code, then it is malformed XML. At least the `&` needs to be escaped, and `>` and `<` should rather not occur untreated either. It might(!) be that this is what the error message refers to, that the upload tool sees `>` in your element contents and thinks that’s HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I hastily pasted from a browser by accident. I updated the code to reflect what I've actually tried submitting.

Comment: You're submitting this by telling Facebook a URL to fetch the data from, correct? In that case, it might be the Content-Type header your server sends - if has not been instructed to serve this with an appropriate MIME type for RSS/XML, it might be falling back to a default `text/html`, and that could explain why it says. "HTML format isn't supported." Call the URL in your browser and use the dev tools/network panel to verify what Content-Type response header the server sends.